# populate and disable text field depending on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Unfortunately i'm not too familiar with javascript/jQuery. I have a form with a dropdown. What i need to do is to populate a text field depending on the selection of the dropdown. First voice of the dropdown is "other" so the text field must be writable, then from the second i want to assign a value automatically and disable the text field.

The value of the dropdown will be saved in the db so it must remains the name of the option.

I found several solutions with google but none of them fits my needs...hope someone could help me.

Comment: Please show us what markup you already have and what scripting alternatives you have tried. We're really not here to do the work for you, just giving you a helping hand if you're stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the functionality you're looking for, there are a few basic things you'll need to learn.

#### jQuery Selectors

First, if you aren't already familiar with jQuery's selector syntax, [learn about it here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp).

#### The .change() Event

Next, you'll need to know how to bind to the dropdown menu's `.change` event. One way to do this is `$('#dropdownId').change(function() { ... });`, which is just a shortcut for `$('#dropdownId').on('change', function() { ... });` .  Within the callback functions, you can access the dropdown element with `this` and as a result, the jQuery object with `$(this)`.

We can then grab the dropdown's value with $(this).val() and use some basic logic to enable/disable the textbox and set its value.

#### Enabling/Disabling the textbox

In order to enable/disable the textbox, you can use: $('#txt').removeAttr('disabled');`and`$('#txt').attr('disabled', 'true');` respectively.

**Example**
I've combined all of these for you in an example fiddle to show you how you can put these together in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/wDaWr/). Let me know if you have any questions about how it works :)

Comment: ok thanks a lot! for what i have to do i ended up editing your code as follows: `$('#txt').val();` and then i will need to do an `else if ( $(this).val() == "opt1") { $('#txt').attr('disabled', 'true').val(2); }` for each dropdown element as i will need to specify a "price" for each voice. is it correct this way?

Comment: Using an `elseif` for each option is a bit burdensome. The easiest way to do what I think you're going for is by simply by adding a value attribute to the option, and since '.val()' is designed to first retrieve the `value` attribute and then use the innerHTML only when there's to value attribute, you don't even have to change the javascript :) Here's an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/wDaWr/5/) . Let me know if this is what you were looking for and if it makes sense..

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fiddle for you...

http://jsfiddle.net/G3V3v

**HTML**:

```
<select id="ddl">
    <option value="0">[ Other ]</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>
<input id="txt" />
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('#ddl').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 0) {
        $('#txt').val('').removeAttr("disabled").focus();
    } else {
        $('#txt').val($(this).children('option:selected').text());
        $('#txt').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: if you are using `jquery 1.9+`, you have to disable textboxes with `prop`, instead of adding/removing `disabled` attribute:

`$("#txt").prop("disabled", true); //disable`

Comment: @kpull1 Thanks. Yes of course. I had this code lying around on my machine from v1.4 era!!